# Picasso wont load images stored in Firebase hosting URL

Tags: firebase, picasso, firebase-hosting

I use a simple picasso library code to load an image stored in firebase hosting URL, the code looks like this.

```
Picasso.get().load(UR).into(ImageView);
```

The code is working well with other hosting services, it just wont load any images hosted on Firebase although I can open the images in the browser.

The code was working for a while then suddenly it stopped loading the images, it can load any image from any other URL, it just wont load them from the Firebase hosting location.

I have activated the logging and I have the following errors

```
06-27 11:02:46.281 13673-13818/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R1]+1ms 
06-27 11:02:46.281 13673-14017/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+1ms 
06-27 11:02:46.961 13673-13818/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R1]+679ms 
06-27 11:02:46.991 13673-14052/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+702ms 
06-27 11:02:47.621 13673-13818/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R1]+1339ms 
06-27 11:02:47.621 13673-14061/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+1339ms 
06-27 11:02:47.621 13673-13818/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+1340ms for error
06-27 11:02:47.821 13673-13818/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+1541ms 
06-27 11:02:47.831 13673-13673/? D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1]+1550ms HTTP 504
```

Note: I can open the image into a browser without any issue, I also tried glide library and I have the same problems.

Comment: Can you put the code of the project and Manifest

Comment: the code works fine with other hosting services, just wonder why it wont work with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you give permission of internet in manifest file.

Comment: I have it, the code was working previously it just broke for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use `implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'` as suggested  [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1670) refer [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader) for implementation